# How do I use MS C++ Express 2008 to build Perl Unicode::Map on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, build, module

I am currently trying to make the Unicode-Map-0.112 module, but encounter an error, `'0x1'`, that is evidently related to using `nmake`.  I tried to follow suggestions on Perl Monks, i.e.  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=434813

However, I am unable to use ppm's capabilities because I am on a Windows machine without a network connection, and the only other machine is a Mac.  It turns out that MS C++ Express 2008 is installed on the machine, so I would I be able to use it to get past the error?

More error details:

```
cl -c - nologo - GF -W3 -MD...

'cl' is not recognized as an internal...command
operable programe or batch file
NMAKE: fatal error U10777 'cl' : return code '0x1'
Stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that cl.exe is not in your path.  I don't recall if the Express SKU has a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" or not (check your start menu).

If not just find cl.exe (let's say it is c:\path\to\vstools\cl.exe) and do something like:

set PATH=%PATH%;c:\path\to\vstools

Comment: Visual Studio (and Express) should come with a batch script "vcvarsall.bat" or similar, which sets all the proper environment variables -- more than just %PATH%, it also sets the proper paths for includes, libraries, and the Windows SDK.

Comment: The correct thing to do here is to install using the separately downloaded ppm package, not compiling this module with a different compiler than the one used to compile AS Perl. Your choice. Further, I had already provided you with this answer a while ago: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016260/still-nmake-problem-with-unicode-map-0-112-after-trying-vcvarsall-bat/1016294#1016294

Answer (score 0):

Can't you download the required files on the Mac, put them on a USB stick and then use `ppm` to install?

Download on the Mac:

```
$ wget http://trouchelle.com/ppm10/Unicode-Map.ppd
$ wget http://trouchelle.com/ppm10/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-5.10/Unicode-Map-0.112.zip
$ mkdir MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-5.10
$ mv Unicode-Map-0.112.zip MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-5.10
```

Then move to Windows machine. Open up a command prompt, change to the directory containing the ppd file on the USB drive:

```
F:\> ppm install -area site Unicode-Map.ppd
Unpacking Unicode-Map-0.112...done
Generating HTML for Unicode-Map-0.112...done
Updating files in site area...done
110 files installed
```